# Why do negative charges build up at the bottom of a thunder cloud?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics

I understand that thunder clouds are a congregation of millions of water droplets. As water evaporates from the ground, these water molecules rise up and collide with water molecules of the cloud, sometimes ripping off electrons. This creates a seperation between positively charged water droplets moving up inside the cloud, leaving electrons behind. Why do the electrons stay at the bottom of the cloud and not move up due to attraction to the positively charged water droplets?

Comment: [Feynman - Electricity in the atmosphere](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_09.html)